# Segmentation fault with ifstream

Tags: segmentation-fault, ifstream

```
    ifstream fmoa("config/MulticastOutputAdapterConfig.json", ifstream::in);
```

The fault is happening at this line only, with this from gdb:

367             ifstream fmoa("config/MulticastOutputAdapterConfig.json", ifstream::in);
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff1899c85 in ReadMulticastOutputAdapterConfig () at src/MulticastOutputAdapter.cpp:367
367             ifstream fmoa("config/MulticastOutputAdapterConfig.json", ifstream::in);
(gdb) backtrace full
#0  0x00007ffff1899c85 in ReadMulticastOutputAdapterConfig () at src/MulticastOutputAdapter.cpp:367
fmoa = 
root = {m_type = nlohmann::detail::null, m_value = {object = 0x0, array = 0x0, string = 0x0, boolean = false, number_integer = 0, number_unsigned = 0, number_float = 0}}
errs = <error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffe8>

Comment: More context is needed - this line by itself looks good to me.